# How can I append this text instead of replacing it?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet:

```
var b=document.getElementsByClassName('textinput')[0];
b.value=' (Christiansburg)';
var f=document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
f.initEvent('change',true,true);
b.dispatchEvent(f);
void(0);
```

This replaces the content (if any) of the Title of a Google Calendar event with `(Christiansburg)`. I would like for it to instead just append it to whatever content is already there. I've tried a couple of things but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: I was close, I just had the syntax off a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `=` operator

```
b.value  = ' (Christiansburg)';
```

to the `+=` operator which will append your string to the value:

```
b.value += ' (Christiansburg)';
```

Answer (score 1):

`b.value += 'yourtextgoesrighthere';` will do it. The '+' sign is an append operator if used on a string.

Answer (score 1):

To append a string value to an existing string, you may use the `+=` operator for the assignment:

```
b.value += ' (Christiansburg)';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can append strings with the `+` operator. so `"Hello" + " " + "world"` would be `"Hello world"`.

So you could do `b.value = b.value + ' (Christiansburg)';`

Since appending is done quite often, there is a shorthand: `b.value += ' (Christiansburg)'`